# Multi-step flows and view models

Tags: mvvm, reactive-cocoa

When implementing a multi-step flow (e.g. signup), should there just be one overarching view model for the entire flow or should each step have its own view model?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I would say there should be one overarching view model *and* each step should have its own view model. The overarching view model would be a parent to the step view models, and would coordinate their life cycle and validation for among other things.